# Upload to multiple CDN servers simultaneously via FTP or SSH

Tags: windows, sync, ftp, upload, cdn

Right now I'm uploading files like so:

1. Connect to first server
2. Upload to first server
3. Connect to second server
4. Ulpoad to second server
5. And so on..

Is there some software what can ulpoad my files to all my servers at once? 
Or can some kind of FTP synchronization software do that?
E.g. synchronizing my localhost's folders with all my servers?
Localhost is running Windows 7 :)

I have FTP and SSH access to the CDN servers, which run on Linux.

Comment: FTP is preferred, but i'm open to other solutions to :)
Current i have SSH and SFTP to half of servers.

Comment: SCP? Haven't used it myself.
What's the pros between FTP and SFTP/SCP(SSH)? Other than secure connection..

Comment: SCP will probably be easier to script, but it doesn't *really* matter. Do you want the upload process to be run concurrently or don't you care about whether it's sequential? Would it be enough if you had a script that performed these copy operations automatically for a given input folder and a list of destination hosts? (And, am I correct assuming you're on Linux?)

Comment: My host machine is windows 7. But my main server is linux(have ssh access to it), and cdns are copy of cacheable items from main server, than i can also use linux.

Comment: And upload can run sequential :)

Comment: On Windows, I use GoodSync for file synchronization. It's not free though. You can achieve the same effect with Win32 builds of bash and rsync, but that requires some scripting and testing.

Comment: Okay, found it on ThePirateBay. If works, will buy ;) Cheers!

Comment: @billc.cn Works like charm! You should post it as answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you can use GoodSync.

Answer (score 0):

Some hosts may or may not be happy about letting you install/run it, but Dropbox is good for synchronizing the same directory across multiple machines, including collision detection, which can be sorted out after-the-fact using the website to determine what to keep, and what to rename (if any).

http://www.dropbox.com

Of course, by default, you're limited to about 2Gb of space for synchronizing...